# non-existant URL containing a valid parent path returns 200, not 404

Tags: routes, uri

For example, if you add extra parameters to node urls (node/[nid]/extra/s if you go to https://www.drupal.org/node/2536034/test/any/thing/in/here/should/404
it renders the page beacuse the node exists but it should be a 404.
I was able to change that in a menu alter hook inspired by at https://www.drupal.org/node/432384

```
/**
 * Implement hook_get_item_alter().
 *
 * Return a 404 for non-existing paths instead or rendering parent path.
 *
 * @see https://www.drupal.org/node/432384
 */
function mymodule_menu_get_item_alter(&$router_item, $path, $original_map) {
  $parts = array_slice($original_map, 0, MENU_MAX_PARTS);
  $ancestors = menu_get_ancestors($parts);
  // Avoid adding ancestors on admin paths because it breaks views admin ui.
  if ($original_map[0] != 'admin') {
    // Add wildcards to "ancestors" that don't have enough parts.
    foreach ($ancestors as &$ancestor) {
      while (substr_count($ancestor, '/') + 1 < count($parts)) {
        $ancestor .= '/%';
      }
    }
    $router_item = db_query_range('SELECT * FROM {menu_router} WHERE path IN (:ancestors) ORDER BY fit DESC', 0, 1, array(':ancestors' => $ancestors))->fetchAssoc();
  }
```

but this definitely breaks anything that does not completley utilize the menu system. For example, views urls
`admin/structure/views/view/someview/edit/panel_pane_1`

Is there an appropriate way to tackle this?